# Rewrite a header to a request string in nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-ingress

I am trying to rewrite the nginx `x-auth-request-email` header to a request string using the ingress controller annotation like this:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
  set $args user=$http_x_auth_request_email&$args;
```

Which translates to the same line in nginx.conf.

However, `$http_x_auth_request_email` somehow resolves to an empty string in the request while I do observe the expected value in the `x-auth-request-email header`.

Changing `$http_x_auth_request_email` to a more standard header such as `$http_host` works as expected.

Is there a way to make this work?

Here is the full config:

https://gist.github.com/roman-kouzmenko/e6f93f3bf5ca74c018f917a2d3fbf947#file-nginx-conf-L1198

Comment: The annotation seem fine to me... Could you exec into controller pod and see how it looks in the actual config?

Comment: Added a link to the config generated from the ingress.

Comment: When you tested it, did you send the request to `/echo/` location? E.g. `curl https://example.com/echo/?foo=bar`

Comment: yes, exactly, I have a container echoing the request on that location (hub.docker.com/r/brndnmtthws/nginx-echo-headers) I see the following: GET /echo/?user=&foo=bar HTTP/1.1 x-auth-request-email: ACTUAL_EMAIL. If I use any of the non-auth headers, it strangely works as expected.

Comment: I am now thinking that perhaps adding another clean non-ingress nginx sidecar to my services would make this easier although not that efficient resource-wise.

Comment: Wait a moment, I've found the source of the problem: https://gist.github.com/roman-kouzmenko/e6f93f3bf5ca74c018f917a2d3fbf947#file-nginx-conf-L1141

Comment: Seems like it's getting erased after authentication. Maybe you need to use `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-response-headers` annotation (see [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#external-authentication))

Comment: I actually already do have that annotation, otherwise, even the header doesn't appear. I can't rewrite any of the other x- headers as well such as x-forwarded-for. I wonder if it's not related to this.

Comment: You can see in the config that x-forwarded-for is set before `proxy_pass`.

Comment: Can you try this snippet, just in case? `set $args user=$upstream_http_x_auth_request_email&$args;`

Comment: tried it already ;) as well as $authHeader0, none of these work.

Comment: Then I suggest to save the header value into a temporary variable at the server block level (`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet`) and use it later in `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet`. Server block configuration snippet should be evaluated before location rewrite sequences, i.e. header value shouldn't be erased at that moment.

Comment: Doesn't work either unfortunately

Comment: I asked this on the slack k8s channel, will update here if I find a solution